# TutorialsPoint ReactJS Environment Setup Step 5 Can't find package.json file

Tags: reactjs

Currently attempting a TutorialsPoint tutorial:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

I am at **Step 5 - Set Compiler, Server and Loaders**.

My issue is that after I edit the `webpack.config` file I am unable to proceed to the next task as I can't find the correct file: `package.json` containing the line/s:

```
"test" "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" inside "scripts" object.
```

I am 90% sure I have completed the previous steps correctly.

Please forgive if this is a 'noob' question and thank-you.

Comment: You likely forgot the --save tag when npm installing react and react-dom in step 3. That is where the package.json file would have been generated within your application directory.

Comment: Can you/someone tell me what folder / directory (preferably the full path to the file) this package.json file should be in?

Comment: It should be in the root of your App folder. (top level of where ever your application resides)

Full path would be something like C:/projects/MyApp/package.json on windows or ~/projects/MyApp/package.json on linux, depends on where you are storing your app.

Comment: At step 3 after typing 'npm install' I should've typed  'npm install <pkg> --save'. I guess I must of not noticed the line  telling me to do so the first time I tried. But in theory, had I simply used Notepad++ to make a JSON file called package (or something) and saved that to my root directory, would I have accomplished the same thing, assuming I knew what to type in my custom (Notepad++) JSON file?

Comment: Yes, if you knew the exact package.json file there's no reason you couldn't have generated it yourself with notepad++. The only thing --save does is add the package to the dependency section in package.json so that when other people build your project they aren't missing anything.